# Retrieve a Bitmap with a Fixed size

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-resources

When you get a bitmap from a resource for example with:

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);
```

It is automatically scaled depending on the device's screen density. How can I avoid that and retrieve it in its original pixel size whatever the screen density is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "It is automatically scaled"? When you call this method Android takes image from folder `res/drawable-?dpi` - depending on device where app is running. If your `ldpi` folder contains 30*30px image, `mdpi` contains 40*40px image and `hdpi` contains 60*60px, you will get bitmap one of this sizes(depends on device). Android does not change anything.

If you see that on the screen your image scaled somehow, check properties of `ImageView`.

Comment: I have stored a single image in drawable-mdpi, And it is scaled (to higher) when is retrieved from hdpi. I see the redimension calling src.getHeight() or getWidth

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S i9000. Note: I know that if i put the image in drawable-hdpi my phone will decode it with it real size but then other mdpi or ldpi phones will decode it with lower size. What I need is a bitmap with constant size always

Comment: For android "constant size always" is very, very bad idea, because if image looks good for your phone it will be too small or too big for other phones. Look this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Addev images in drawable-nodpi should not be scaled. And I think drawable folder with no density qualifier works the same way.

Comment: Yes is for a image editing program and I need no redimensions in order to the result and the original have the same size. I think the @harism solution will work. Thanks to both for your help